# Printing lists of dictionary keys within a molecular interval

Tags: python, dictionary, sequence, biopython, fasta

For an assignment I need to implement a previous function into a new function that, given a FASTA file and a min and max molecular weight, returns a list of sequence IDs for sequences that have a molecular weight within the given interval.

This is my previous function:

```
def Dict_MW(file_name):
with open(file_name) as seq_file:
    seq_dict = {}
    for record in SeqIO.parse(seq_file, 'fasta'):
        d = IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values
        ambiguous_dna = list(map("".join, product(*map(d.get, record))))
        mol_weight = []
        for seq in ambiguous_dna:
            mol_weight.append(SeqUtils.molecular_weight(seq))
        tuple = (min(mol_weight),max(mol_weight))
        if min(mol_weight) != max(mol_weight):
            seq_dict[record.id] = (min(mol_weight), max(mol_weight))
        else:
            seq_dict[record.id] = min(mol_weight)
    print(seq_dict)
```

This function prints a dictionary with as keys the IDs and molecular weights are the values.

This is the new function:

```
   def List(file_name, mw_min, mw_max):
    with open(file_name) as seq_file:
        seq_dict = {}
        ID = []
        for record in SeqIO.parse(seq_file, 'fasta'):
            d = IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values
            ambiguous_dna = list(map("".join, product(*map(d.get, record))))
            mol_weight = []
            for seq in ambiguous_dna:
                mol_weight.append(SeqUtils.molecular_weight(seq))
            tuple = (min(mol_weight),max(mol_weight))
            if min(mol_weight) != max(mol_weight):
                seq_dict[record.id] = (min(mol_weight), max(mol_weight))
            else:
                seq_dict[record.id] = min(mol_weight)
            for values in mol_weight:
                if mw_min <= values <= mw_max:
                    ID.append(seq_dict.keys())
        print(ID)
```

It works but it's not the right output. It gives all the IDs instead of only the onces that are within the given molecular interval.

The Fasta file that I use:

```
>seq_7009 random sequence
DGRGGGWAVCVAACGTTGAT
>seq_418 random sequence
GAGCTGVTATST
>seq_9143_unamb random sequence
ACCGTTAAGCCTTAG
>seq_2888 random sequence
RVCCWDGARATAGBCGC
>seq_1101 random sequence
CSAATGYGATNBTA
>seq_107 random sequence
WGDGHGCDCTYANGTTWCA
>seq_6946 random sequence
TCVMBRAGRSGTCCAWA
>seq_6162 random sequence
YWBGCKTGCCAAGCGCDG
>seq_504 random sequence
ADDTAACCCTCTTKA
>seq_3535 random sequence
KKGTACACCAG
>seq_4077 random sequence
SRWSCRTTRVAGDCC
> seq_1626_unamb random sequence
GGATATTACCTA
```

Comment: Indentation in Python is really important. The code as shown would not even run due to wrong indentation.

Comment: An most imporantly: I think you are getting the wrong result because the indentation of print(ID) is wrong - should be further left, aligned with the with-statement, I guess.

Comment: If I change the identation I still get the same results

Answer (score -1):

This is how I am trying to solve the question, I assume we have the same python assignment.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqUtils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## function description

def unamb_MW(filename):
    mol_weight_list = []
    mol_weight_dict = dict()
    nucleotides ={'A','T', 'C', 'G'} # om de nucleotiden te defineren zodat bij ambiguous seq, de N als niet nucleotide wordt herkend.
    with open(filename) as file: #omdat de filename een fasta bestand is moeten we die omzetten naar string zodat we de biopython functie SeqUtils kunnen gebruiken voor de moleculaire massa te berekenen.
        for record in SeqIO.parse(file, "fasta"): #met SeqIO.parse wordt de fasta file klaar gezet om gelezen te worden.
            for nucl in record: #om alle seq in de fasta file te doorlopen.
                if nucl in nucleotides: # om ambiguous seq van unambiguous seq te scheiden, want dit zal ons een error vermjden van SeqUtils omdat SeqUtils enkel met ambiguous seq werkt.
                    continue
                else:
                    print(str(record.id)+": is ambiguous") # om ambiguous seq te printen zo kan je de fasta open doen en controleren als je code wel zeker de ambiguous buiten laat.
                    break
            else:
                mol_weight= Bio.SeqUtils.molecular_weight(record.seq) #biopython functie om moleculaire massa te berekenen.
                print(str(record.id)+": is unambiguous & molecular weight = "+str(mol_weight))
                mol_weight_list.append(mol_weight)
                mol_weight_dict[str(record.id)] = mol_weight
    #print(mol_weight_dict)
    return mol_weight_dict

def MW_list(filename, min_MW, max_MW):
    mol_weight = unamb_MW(filename)
    for record in mol_weight:
        if min_MW < mol_weight[record]:
            if mol_weight[record] < max_MW:
                print('\n', [record])
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass ´´´
#If you're taking the course computational biology then we have the same assignment.
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a short rationale for your answer before the code? It will help us know what to look for.

Comment: @WhooNo This first (unamb_MW(filename)) function is used to just calculate the molecular weight of unambiguous DNA sequences. 
Then I used the (MW_list(filename, min_MW, max_MW)) function to print a list with sequence ID in the given mol_weight interval.